# If test for NaN

Tags: xslt

I have a xsl template with the code

```
 <xsl:if test="(base_extra_fee_rule_amount='75.0000')">
```

But I want the code to run if there any value for that field or don't run the code if the field is NaN

I tried varations of

```
<xsl:if test="not(base_extra_fee_rule_amount='NaN')">
```

But that doesn't work, is there a simple way of achieving this?

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? If the amount is not a number, then the result of your current test will be false. Why is that a problem?

Comment: <xsl:if test="base_extra_fee_rule_amount!=''">

Comment: its a export template, so if there is a value for that field, i want the following  code to be run (which pulls out that value + other things), if there is no value I don't want the code to run eg that line is not needed

Comment: If that line is not needed, then you should not process it all. IOW, the problem is not in the code snippet you posted but higher up, where this code is being applied.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, its only not needed, if the value is NaN.  The if test is to see if there is any value in the "base_extra_fee_rule_amount" before running the next lines of code

Comment: @Ajeet Singh that seems to work ( thought I had tried something like that, but guess not),  If you want to put that as an answer

Comment: @PaddyD
<xsl:template match="base_extra_fee_rule_amount!=''">
<xsl:text>@@@@</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

Comment: @Ajeet Singh sorry i meant, if you want to put that as answer to this question I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to test whether X is `NaN` is `(X=X)`, because only if X is NaN will that expression return false.

If you want a more readable expression, then `string(number(X))='NaN'` does the job.

Note, however, the operand `base_extra_fee_rule_amount` returns either an element node or nothing. Only a value of type number can be NaN, so an element isn't going to be NaN until you try to convert it to a number. That can happen explicitly or implicitly, and the details depend on whether you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, and in the latter case on whether it's schema-aware. At this stage it's not clear entirely what test you want to apply. Are you interested in testing whether the element has the string value "NaN", or are you interested in testing whether it has a value that is not a number?

Comment: ultimately i was being stupid,   'base_extra_fee_rule_amount' is a new field that sometimes will have a value in it.  When testing i was using using old records (orders) that where made when  'base_extra_fee_rule_amount' did not exist, so it was returning 'NaN'. So for new records the value is defaulting to 0.0000 when there is no "extra_fee", so I only need a simple '<xsl:if test="not(base_extra_fee_rule_amount='0.0000')">'

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your purpose is here.

In general, you can select/match nodes with valid numeric values using a predicate - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="amount[number()=number()]">
```

Answer (score -1):

PaddyD:-

Thanks for notified:-

```
    <xsl:template match="base_extra_fee_rule_amount!=''"> <xsl:text>@@@@</xsl:text> </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question. An empty string is not at all the same thing as NaN.